# ng test not working karma not able to start " ChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL."

Tags: angular, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless, angular-test

I am not able to start angular tests due to unknown reasons. it says endlessly, "Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing, ChromeHeadless was not killed by SIGKILL in 200ms, continuing".

I have no idea what is the problem? What is missing at my side?
Attached is the screenshot for this.

[image]

Following is karma.conf.js

```
  //Karma configuration file, see link for more information
 //https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

const { join } = require('path');
  const getBaseKarmaConfig = require('../../karma.conf');

  module.exports = function(config) {
     const baseConfig = getBaseKarmaConfig();
     config.set({
    ...baseConfig,
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      ...baseConfig.coverageIstanbulReporter,
      dir: join(__dirname, '../../coverage/apps/login/')
    }
  });
};

and complete karma.conf.js is :

    // Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

const { join } = require('path');
const { constants } = require('karma');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        basePath: process.cwd() + '/apps/login',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-spec-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        proxies : {
            '/assets/': 'assets/'
        },
        client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: join(__dirname, '../../coverage'),
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
            emitWarning: true,
            thresholds: {
                statements: 80,
                lines: 80,
                branches: 0,
                functions: 70
            }
        },
        reporters: ['spec', 'junit', 'kjhtml'],
        junitReporter: { outputFile: 'TEST-results.xml' },
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: constants.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        singleRun: true,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
        files: [
            { pattern: 'src/assets/img/*.png', watched: false, included:false, nocache:false, served:true },
            { pattern: 'src/assets/img/*.svg', watched: false, included:false, nocache:false, served:true },
            { pattern: 'src/assets/*.json', watched: false, included:false, nocache:false, served:true }
        ]
    };
};
```

Comment: I realized that it is going to find the 'Chrome.exe' binary at some other path othe than that where it is actually placed. Can any body point me out how to direct so that it should point out the right location. How can somebody set launcher at karma.config.js

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: @leonheess : If I remember correctly, I had to modify the ocnfig files and had to put the correct address of chrome.exe by locating it from my File Explorer.
Sorry it's almost 2 years back I encountered that problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using puppeteer to install ChromeHeadless? Try specifying the path to the executable and see if that gets ChromeHeadless to launch properly.

Here is a sample karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```